# Adding description from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF Code First (but all the tables already exist, we're using Reverse POCO Generator). I have 3 related tables - Sales Channels (`SChannels`), `ScsgLink` and `SpGroup` table (that has `GroupNo` and Descrip columns). I have the following code right now to get the Sales Channel by `Id`

```
public override SChannels GetById(object id)
{
   var sChannel = _siriusContext.SChannels.Include("ScsgLink")         
                                .Where(x => x.ChannelId == (Int32)id)
                                .First();
   return sChannel;
}
```

I've added `GroupDescription` property to the `ScsgLink` class, e.g.

```
public partial class ScsgLink
{
    [NotMapped]
    public String GroupDescription { get; set; }
}
```

The rest of the code for that class is auto-generated by Reverse POCO generator.

So, my problem right now is to somehow adding the description from the `SpGroup` table when I retrieve the Sales Channel by Id in the code I shown.

Just to clarify, this is the SChannels class:

```html
 // Reverse navigation
        public virtual ICollection<Max4Sale> Max4Sale { get; set; } // max4sale.FK_Max4Sale_SChannels_ChannelID
        public virtual ICollection<ScsgLink> ScsgLink { get; set; } // SCSGLink.FK_SCSGLink_SChannels
```

And this is what I have in the link table class:

```html
 // Foreign keys
        public virtual SChannels SChannels { get; set; } // FK_SCSGLink_SChannels
        public virtual SpGroup SpGroup { get; set; } // FK_SCSGLink_sp_group
```

So, I need to bring descrip column from the SpGroup when I retrieve SChannels row by Id with the related rows from the Link table. And here I'm not sure of the syntax.

Comment: If you use [NotMapped] with the GroupDescription, this field will not create in ScsgLink table.

Comment: I know and I don't want it in this table. As I explained, that column should come from another table. I am just not certain on the syntax of how to bring that column when I retrieve the info from ScsgLink table using include syntax

Comment: I've added a bit of clarification into my post. We have database designed and populated, but we also have our models in code by using Reverse POCO Generator.